# When colliding, not changing the bool variable

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, boolean

I am trying to write a script in C# for unity. This script is to make my sprite jump. I require the sprite to only able to jump when it is touching the ground, so when the bool 'isJumping' is set to false.

When using the script in Unity3D (Although I'm using the 2D pre sets and am building a 2D game) I am able to jump when the game is first ran, but after hitting space the bool is set to true, and when I collide with the grounded which is tagged 'Ground' the bool does not get set to false meaning I can not jump again.

So I am wondering what I have done wrong, and why when I collide with 'Ground' the bool is not set to false. Thank you for your help in advance! Below, is the code. :)

```cs
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Jump1 : MonoBehaviour {

    public float jumpHeight;
    public bool isJumping = false;

    void Start() {

    }

    void Update() {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            if (isJumping == false)
            {
               rigidbody2D.AddForce(Vector2.up * jumpHeight);
               isJumping = true;
            }
        }
    }

    void onCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col) {
        if (col.gameObject.tag == "Ground")
        {
            isJumping = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you set breakpoints? Do you know if the `onCollisionEnter2D` method is even called?

Comment: I'm unsure of what break points are, I'll be sure to check those out. 

I did 'Print("Test");' and it did not print anything to the console, so I guess this means that 'void onCollisionEnter2D(collision2D col)' isn't working?

Comment: I guess it's not. Why would it be working? Who would call it and why?

Comment: Isn't the sprite that the script is added to calling it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey I guess the problem is that you didn't place rigid body you should add it to the ground or the character it self (if you don't want to use gravity in it just make it equal to zero if you're adding rigidbody2D or uncheck use gravity if you're using rigid body)
if you already have placed rigid body to one of them and it's not working just comment here ill try to think of other reason

Comment: I have indeed added a Rigidbody2D to the character.. 

Nvogit has been talking about who has called it, but if the script is added to the sprite, then the sprite is calling it right? Thanks in advance and for your input! :)

Comment: Are you sure istrigger is not checked ? And if it's not did you change anything with your project settings?and is the sprite is child or a parent of another object?

Comment: Is trigger is not checked, 

I don't relive I've changed any project settings..? I'll start a new project and just import the scripts and see. 

The character and ground are not parents/or children.. :/

Comment: Can you check if the collision function is being called try to print something inside the function(not the if statement..)

Comment: oh oh look at your Function name the letter o in On should be capital letter ... XD

Comment: Thank you @Aodai Irshed! That was the issue, and it works just fine now! :) Thanks so much, this script has taken quite awhile to get working.. But thanks to you I can now continue :)